# Loading with jQuery and Ajax a little Gallery

Tags: jquery, ajax, image

I'm trying on a little gallery with lightbox 2 but I would want learn load more than 100 images in the same page. I mean, I would want preload the little images (100 images * 20 Kb per image). But when somebody click over the image, this one will open and show to user. Also, the user can go to the next one....I've been seeing in most webs, but I don't understand how I can do that.

Could you help me? Could you show me a simple code to put a little image and when do a click over, the image show it bigger (with ajax)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't a direct answer, but I would suggest you use http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/ - the documentation and explanation of use is really helpful and simple. You can have as many images on the page as it picks up all img tags in the class="thumbnails yoxview"!